# Alguém conhece um programa para descompilar um apk e obter o código fonte?

Tags: android, apk

Utilizei o 7zip, porém ele não descompila o código que é o que interessa, ele descompila somente os arquivos xml. Alguém conhece um programa que faça isso? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem essas ferramentas online = http://www.decompileandroid.com/ e http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk, tem também o APK Studio, que faz a engenharia reversa do apk = https://github.com/vaibhavpandeyvpz/apkstudio.

Comment: obrigadão! O javadecompilers funcionou perfeitamente!